# Nginx the "user" directive

Tags: nginx, web, webserver, nginx-config

My Nginx server threw the warning:

```
nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
```

I created nginx-group and nginx-user

```
groupadd --system --gid 7447 nginx-group
adduser --system --gid 7447 --uid 7447 nginx-user
```

The Nginx process owned by my user "nginx-user"

```
bash-4.2$ ps -ef | grep [n]ginx
nginx-u+     1     0  0 08:05 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon off;
nginx-u+     7     1  0 08:05 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
```

The /etc/nginx folder and content owned by the root user

```
bash-4.2$ ls -la /etc/nginx
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   20 Aug  1 07:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   41 Aug  1 08:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   54 Aug  1 07:33 conf.d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1007 May 24 15:35 fastcgi_params
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3957 Aug  1 07:05 mime.types
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Aug  1 07:33 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/nginx/modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2200 Aug  1 07:05 nginx.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  636 May 24 15:35 scgi_params
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22 Aug  1 07:33 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22 Aug  1 07:33 sites-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  664 May 24 15:35 uwsgi_params
```

Anyone can help to fix this warning ?

Comment: That warning is only saying that _because_ you are not starting nginx as root it's ignored. If you want it to take effect, start the process as root - but you don't have to.